# Generate key using PUTTY

Tags: git, gitlab, putty

So I'm learning on  how to use `gitlab` by myself so can be use in future.
I stuck at the generate key part. I've downloaded the `PUTTY`,but don't know how to generate the key.

Currently I follow this [post](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-keytype), but no idea how to select the key.

[image]

Comment: In order to generate a key you have to use [PuTTYGen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen), a tool also included in **WinSCP**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As outlined in your link, you need to use PuTTYgen to generate the key ([8.2 Using PuTTYgen, the PuTTY key generator](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey-puttygen)).

If you downloaded just `putty.exe`, then you'll need to get `puttygen.exe` too, see here:
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Otherwise, if you ran an installer, it's probably installed already.

---

When you've generated a key with PuTTYgen, you'll need to save it.

- PuTTY requires a `*.ppk`
- OpenSSH requires a different key format (run PuTTYgen, and generate a key, then see the `Conversions -> Export OpenSSH key` menu item.

You might need to use an OpenSSH key for your installation of git, so watchout...

---

Once you have a key, open PuTTY and navigate to `Connection -> SSH -> Auth`, then select your `*.ppk` file in the "*Private key file for authentication*" box.

**NOTE:** If you're planning to login using a specific `git` account (rather than a user account), then I would also recommend that you select `Close window on exit: Never` from the `Session` pane. This way PuTTY won't just "disappear" if your server provides a list of repositories that you can access and closes the session.

Comment: Thanks, I installing `puttygen.exe` now. Will update you later.